# How to mount Ext3 drive in Cygwin?

Tags: mount, cygwin, ext3

I want to mount and fully operate an Ext3-formatted USB drive in Cygwin under Windows XP. How can I do this?

Comment: Cygwin only offers a Linux API for applications, it doesn't let you use Linux kernel modules like the one for the ext3 filesystem, on Windows. Though as [Darth Android](http://superuser.com/users/19841/darth-android) said, there are [other ways](http://superuser.com/questions/315351/how-to-mount-ext3-drive-in-cygwin#2357) of seeing ext3 filesystems on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can use cygwin to mount the drive, but you can use the [Ext2fs](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) driver to mount the drive in windows natively and access it under `/cygdrive/<driveletter>/` in Cygwin.

Comment: Ya i can mount it with Ext2fsd.. but not listed under /cygdrive/ in Cygwin. I mean, that drive is appearing under drive lists of "My Computer" but not appearing inside /cygdrive/ in Cygwin.

Comment: Using the mount command in Cygwin allows to mount a path in Windows to a path in Cygwin, I believe. Try using that with Ext2fs.